# Unable to generate resources using laravel-code-generator in Laravel 5.8

Tags: laravel-code-generator

I created a fresh Laravel project v5.8. Then installed the latest version of the Laravel Code Generator (2.3) but I'm unable to generate resources. I've read your release notes for 2.3 and I'm not seeing where I'm making a mistake on the installation or the commands I keep the output below:

> php artisan create:scaffold Test generates the output below:

```
Exception  : The file
resources/laravel-code-generator/sources/tests.json was not found!

  at /Users/Sites/Laravel/lms/vendor/crestapps/laravel-code-generator/src/Models/Resource.php:686
    682|     {
    683|         $fileFullname = Config::getResourceFilePath($filename);
    684| 
    685|         if (!File::exists($fileFullname)) {
  > 686|             throw new Exception('The file ' . $fileFullname . ' was not found!');
    687|         }
    688| 
    689|         return File::get($fileFullname);
    690|     }

  Exception trace:

  1   CrestApps\CodeGenerator\Models\Resource::jsonFileContent("tests.json")
      /Users/Sites/Laravel/lms/vendor/crestapps/laravel-code-generator/src/Models/Resource.php:549

  2   CrestApps\CodeGenerator\Models\Resource::fromFile("tests.json", "CrestApps")
      /Users/Sites/Laravel/lms/vendor/crestapps/laravel-code-generator/src/Commands/Framework/CreateScaffoldCommand.php:70

  Please use the argument -v to see more details.
```

I'm getting a similar output when trying to create resources from a database table. I'm using the php artisan resource-file:from-database [model-name] command.

I read online that it may have to do with the Laravel storage folder not having the correct permissions but I've tried that and it didn't work. Cleared and config the cache, `composer dump-autoload`, etc... But nothing has worked.
I'm also noticing that the generator does not publish the configuration file on your sample video on your website. I have tried to publish the config file using the vendor:publish command but it generates a somewhat empty file, only has this option: `'files_upload_path' => 'uploads'`. The folder for the generator located inside the resources folder does not contain a config file.

Comment: Where you able to get this to work? If not, I recoomand you use version 2.2.* as it is the most stable version, v2.3 is still under pre-release and does not have full documentation. Anyhow, you may want to ensure that the `/resources/laravel-code-generator/sources/tests.json` file was actually created. a new file would be creating using the following command `php artisan resource-file:create Test --fields=id,name,description`. When creating resources from existing database should create that file for you as well

Comment: I have the same issue on v2.3 with Laravel 5.8.10. It seems like the "vendor:publish" command is not creating the "resources/laravel-code-generator" directory. I was not able to get this to work so far.

Comment: This has been reported as a bug and should be fixed as of v2.3.2 release. Please upgrade your package and try it again